# How to get byte slice of large file?

Tags: go, io

I have a large file stored at `path` and want to efficiently cut out a byte slice `text` from index `x` to index `y`. This is my code so far:

```
content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
check(err)
text = content[x:y]
// do something with text
```

The problem with my current implementation is that I run into memory issues with large files.

```
fatal error: runtime: out of memory
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can open the file using `os.Open`, use `File.Seek` to get to the `x` position, and read the next `y-x` bytes in the file. This way you don't need to read the entire file to get the slice you are after.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [yazgazan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1147580/yazgazan) I was able to come up with a solution by using File.ReadAt:

```
f, err := os.Open(path)
check(err)
text := make([]byte, y-x)
_, err = f.ReadAt(text, int64(x))
```